envsubst doesn't work with Nginx and Docker Compose
After starting docker compose I expected the entrypoint command to change the placeholder in my template to my real domain, but instead when i checkt the nginx config I found my template without my domain.
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./configs/nginx/nginx.conf.template:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template
      - ./configs/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    env_file:
      - .env
    entrypoint: /bin/sh -c "envsubst '\$DOMAIN' < /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.template > /etc/nginx/nginx.conf && nginx -g 'daemon off;'"
    networks:
      - proxy

networks:
  proxy:
    driver: bridge
    name: proxy

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ${DOMAIN};
        location = / {
            return 200;
        }
        location / {
            return 404;
        }
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name ntfy.${DOMAIN};
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://ntfy:80;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
}

DOMAIN=localhost

After that discovery I tried to exec into the container and to my suprise, when I run the exact same envsubst cmd it changes the nginx config and after a quick
nginx -s reload
everything works.

The nginx image can do this on its own, provided you're willing to template default.conf rather than the root nginx.conf.  If you delete the entrypoint: override, does the envsubst pass built into the image do what you need?  (You can also delete the networks: and container_name: to further simplify the setup.)
